# Job Scheduling: Using while(1) and time.sleep()

Tags: python, python-2.7, job-scheduling

On regular intervals ( every 10 minutes), I need to fetch data from a local database and send it to a remote server using python requests.

```
while(1):
  fetch_data()
  process_data()
  send_to_server(data)
  time.sleep(600)
```

Is this reliable if I am catching all the errors, keeping the provision for retransmission of data if it fails?
Or, should I just use appscheduler?

Comment: What do you mean by reliable? As in, will it run for a month, a year or maybe ten? As in, will it crash randomly or recover from failure? As in, is it vulnerable to attacks, back pressure or other external error sources? As in, will it recover from system failures, reboots, reprovisioning? What exactly is your measure for "reliable"?

Comment: It's not correct solution. You should set up your OS to run your python script once per 10 minute. Script should contain only execution code.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Thank you for replying, Sir! Reliable as in I won't be scolded by senior programmers, for it being so lame and faulty :). Also, it should work properly for straight 10 hours.

Comment: If you just want to run the same thing every ten minutes, using ``while True:`` and ``time.sleep`` is perfectly fine. You may want to account for the time it actually takes to fetch, process and send your data, but that is about it.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: Everything finishes off within the time limit. My only worry is that people go for cron-jobs/appscheduler, and here I am using a `while(True)` and `time.sleep()`, I just wanted an opinion about this...thank you very much for calling it "perfectly fine"

Comment: @OlvinRoght: Thanks for replying, Sir. Could you please suggest an alternative/improvement.

Comment: @potatoman, You've mentioned alternative in previous comments. If you need to execute same code number of times with big delays you should use task scheduler of your OS. In Linux it's crontab, in Windows - schtasks.